# Extracting specific data MySQL multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

Couldn't really find a suitable title so I will explain here. I have two tables: Citizens and Sects. The relevant columns for this question are as such :

Citizens: full_name, age, power_rank , sect_id.

Sects: ID, Sect_name.

What I want to do, is add a column to Sects which I will name 'Sect_Master'. A citizen is qualifiable to be a sect_master if they are of power_rank 9 , and in the case there are multiple ones, We will choose the oldest and assign him as sect_master in the Sects table.

So my question is basically how to get a list of only one person by sect who is level 9 and the oldest available ?

EDIT:

Looks like this is the answer:

```
WITH possible AS (
  SELECT c.sect_id, c.full_name, c.age, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sect_id ORDER BY age DESC) AS rn
  FROM citizens AS c WHERE power_rank = 9
)
SELECT * FROM possible WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this problem really related to PHP?

Comment: just noticed it and removed ! Well basically I did try multiple versions using grouping by amd ordering by age desc so the oldest appears first but What I want is just a table with the sect_id (unique), and the name of the person who power_rank is 9 and also the oldest one in **that sect**. I am guessing the solution for this might be window functions but they are not my forte so would like some guidance @NicoHaase